# How to pass an action if parent class can be null in C#?

Tags: c#

I want to send actions through a parameter using the following simplified code below.

```
public class Class1
{
    public Class2 myClass = null;
    public static void Start()
    {
        Class3.Run(myClass.WriteText("Hi"));
    }
}

public class Class2
{
    public Class2()
    {

    }

    public void WriteText(string text)
    {
        Console.Writeline(text);
    }
}

public class Class3
{
    public static void Run(Action action)
    {
        //Some code that causes a 60 second delay
        action();
    }
}
```

This code shows that if i call for `Start()` in `Class1` then I want to send an action called `WriteText()` from Class2 to Class3 `Run()`.

However, since `Class2 myClass = null` at some possible moments the passing through does not work because `myClass` is null. Ofcourse.

I want to be able to pass through the action `WriteText` even if its class is null. Then wait in Class3 for 60 seconds and perform the action. If `myClass` is still null then ofcourse dont send.

I have trouble explaining my situation, im sorry.
The code above here is what I am trying, but ofcourse this does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why not try something like:

```
public class Class1
{
    public static Class2 myClass = null;
    public static void Start()
    {
        Class3.Run(() => myClass?.WriteText("Hi"));
    }
}
```

the '?' will make sure function is not called if instance is null :)

Answer (score 1):

The code example you've given is perhaps a poor example of what you're trying to achieve, but I think I have the gist of it.

Actions, like all delegate types, are [closures](https://www.simplethread.com/c-closures-explained/) that encapsulate both a method reference and a reference to an object instance - although for closures over static methods that instance reference may be null. Once you create an instance of a closure there's no way to modify the object it refers to. If you're expecting that `myClass` will change then you'll have to take a more indirect approach, using a method that references the `myClass` field in `Class1`:

```
Class3.Run(() => myClass.WriteText("Hi"));
```

The lambda expression will be called when the 'some code that causes a 60 second delay' has completed, and it will fetch the *current* value of `myClass` at that point in time. You'll have to change `myClass` to be a static field to access it without a reference to an instance of `Class1` of course, otherwise that won't compile either. And you'll have to set `myClass` somewhere in the process or it'll error on that line.